# Screen record on iPad with Bluetooth microphone

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, microphone, screen-recording

I am trying to make a video in which I write on a note app and use screen recording to capture it on an iPad Pro.  However, the built-in mic makes the audio quality fairly bad, so I am trying to use a headset connected by Bluetooth.  When I record, the audio quality isn't improved at all and I suspect that it's because the recording is still using the built-in mic rather than the connected Bluetooth input.  I can't find any settings controlling which input device is used.

I also know the headset works and records higher quality audio since I have been able to use it on a Windows computer.  Unfortunately I can't do this work on my Windows computer because that doesn't have good enough screen-writing abilities.

Does anyone know how to make screen recording on iPad which uses a Bluetooth input?

Comment: Go to the Bluetooth settings. Is the headset you’re using detected as a headphone or headset?  The first has no mic whereas the second does. Do you see the headset icon in the top bar?

Comment: @Allan So I have connected the headset and gone to the Bluetooth options for this device.  Where it says to select device type the only options are: Car Stereo, Headphone, Hearing Aid, Speaker, Other.  I tried selecting other since no other option sounds ideal.

Comment: @Allan I do see an icon at the top, although I couldn't tell you the difference between a headset and headphone icon.

Comment: @Allan Hey, just wanted to let you know that I actually figured this out.  It had to do with the Logitech app on my iPad needing an update.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!  Upvoting your answer.  Hope to see some more challenging questions and even some answers in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out -- it turns out that my headset is a Logitech device, and I hadn't updated my iPad's Logi Tune app in a long time.  So I went to the app, it prompted me to update.  After it did, when screen recording, it now picks up the audio from the headset.